# Does the Youtube Data API have the ability to premiere?

Tags: api, youtube

Does the Youtube Data API v3 have the ability to upload a video as a premiere instead of an instant upload?
I found that it is possible to use `status.privacyStatus = private` with `status.publishAt = ISODATE` to delay the publishing, but it does not include the premiere function used in youtube studio.

I also cannot find anything about it on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Though, I found something about LiveStreamingDetails.scheduledStartTime (same doc page) but this didnt seem to mean anything to video's (only livestreams, thus in the name).

Comment: Please read their docs or search in github for premiere, someone else could have done this before.